# Issue with updating a textblock in WP7 with a timer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, timer

I working on an app that will (as a minor subset of it's functionality) provide a countdown timer. However, there can and will be instances where there are multiple count downs going at the same time. Each Count Down has it's own pivot item in a pivot view. Since these countdowns are dynamically created, I'm adding the textblock (that serves as the output for the time remaining) for each countdown to a list, and I've set a timer to call a method that cycles through each one of those textblocks in the list and update them accordingly. However, I'm receiving an exception of "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" but I'm not entirely sure why. I am being told it's a error of "Invalid cross-thread access."

Here's the line that is the offending line:

```
c.Label.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { c.Label.Text = timeRemaining; });
```

Here is the full method:

```
private static void TimeRemainingCallback(object state)
    {
        if (countDowns.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (CountDown c in countDowns)
        {
            DateTime rightNow = DateTime.Today;

            if (c.ExpirationDate >= rightNow)
            {
                DateTime offsetExpiration = c.ExpirationDate.Add(c.LocalNow);
                TimeSpan timeDifference = offsetExpiration.Subtract(rightNow);


                String timeRemaining = "";
                String timeDays = "";
                String timeHours = "";
                String timeMinutes = "";
                String timeSeconds = "";

                if (timeDifference.Days == 1)
                {
                    timeDays = "1 Day";
                }
                else
                {
                    timeDays = timeDifference.Days + " Days";
                }

                if (timeDifference.Hours == 1)
                {
                    timeHours = "1 Hour";
                }
                else
                {
                    timeHours = timeDifference.Hours + " Hours";
                }

                if (timeDifference.Minutes == 1)
                {
                    timeMinutes = "1 Minute";
                }
                else
                {
                    timeMinutes = timeDifference.Minutes + " Minutes";
                }

                if (timeDifference.Seconds == 1)
                {
                    timeSeconds = "1 Second";
                }
                else
                {
                    timeSeconds = timeDifference.Seconds + " Seconds";
                }

                if (timeDifference.Days == 0 && timeDifference.Hours >= 1)
                {
                    timeRemaining = timeHours + " " + timeMinutes;
                }
                else if (timeDifference.Days == 0 && timeDifference.Hours == 0 && timeDifference.Minutes >= 1)
                {
                    timeRemaining = timeMinutes + " " + timeSeconds;
                }
                else if (timeDifference.Days == 0 && timeDifference.Hours == 0 && timeDifference.Minutes == 0)
                {
                    timeRemaining = timeSeconds;
                }
                else
                {
                    timeRemaining = timeDays + " " + timeHours + " " + timeMinutes;
                }

                c.Label.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { c.Label.Text = timeRemaining; });
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I create the timer, the only time the CallBack is mentioned:

```
Timer updateRemainingTime = new Timer(TimeRemainingCallback, null, 0, 1000);
```

The list is really full of objects that contain a datetime and a textblock (which here is called label) thus the c.Label deal.

timeRemaining is the string of the time remaining that is formed in the timercallback.

Any ideas of what's going on here? Any better ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code that shows how you are modifying `timeRemaining` and where it is declared?

Comment: @Dennis I've added the full method call...

Comment: Also, where is `TimeRemainingCallback` invoked/wired (post code)?

Comment: @Dennis, it's kind of hard to post, because each one of these countdowns is being created by what's being returned by a webservice call. But basically, after InitializeComponent(); in the constructor, I call the service call, and once it's done creating all of the pivots, and is about to exit the service call callback, it creates the timer.

Comment: @Dennis I will say, it seems to work at least once before it fails, as I set the text of the textblock to "test" when it's first created, and it does get set to the proper string...

Comment: The CountDown.Label property... are you creating that dynamically in code? If you are, make sure you are creating them on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the `Dispatcher` for the entire loop iteration, and remove your current Dispatcher invocation.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    foreach (CountDown c in countDowns)
    {
       // Actions here.
       c.Label.Text = timeRemaining;
    }
});
```

I am assuming you have `countDowns` bound to the list UI control you're working with.

Comment: How do I use Dispatcher without any objects?

Comment: Where are you using the `Timer` anyway? If it's inside a `Page`, then you can use the `Dispatcher` associated with it without referencing the source object.

Comment: It's inside the page... but within the callback method for a async service call (because at that point, I know the data is populated to be manipulated by the timer).

Comment: As long as its inside the page, you can use the `Dispatcher` the way I showed. Just try it.

Comment: Well, I got the dispatcher to show up by removing the static from the callback declaration. However, while I can't see it fail, I think it is failing as the text is never updated... (except the first time).

Comment: One thing worth mentioning here is that you should not operate with visual entities the way you do. `CountDown` should be a separate class that only carries data and not UI elements. You can bind your Pivot to an `ObservableCollection` and simply have an internal `Pivot.ItemTemplate` that will bind object values to the template controls.

Comment: @Hosemeyer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2076/discussion-between-dennis-delimarsky-and-hosemeyer)

Comment: After switching to an observablecollection, I finally got this to work. Hooray!